# "syntax error: unexpected end of file" simple script

Tags: bash, scripts

i need some help for a very siple script, i don't get were the fault is.
The script :

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i s
declare -i m
declare -i h

if [ "$3" < 50 ]; then s=$3+10  m=$2  h=$1
        else if ["$2" < 50 ];
                then s=$3-50  m=$2+1  h=$1
                    else s=$1-50  m=$2-50  h=$1+1 fi 
fi 

echo "$h:$m:$s"
```

The script add 10sc to the time we've entered.

I get this error message : "sub_change_dirrect: line 14: syntax error: unexpected end of file"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three obvious errors:

- On the line `else s=$1-50  m=$2-50  h=$1+1 fi`, the word `fi` is not treated as a keyword, because it is not the first word in the command. To the shell, this looks like three assignments that apply to the command `fi`. If you ever got to execute this line, you'd see an error `bash: fi: command not found`. Put `fi` on a line of its own (or put a `;` before it).
- `[ "$3" < 50 ]` is the same as `[ "$3" ] < 50` — it's the command `[ … ]` (which can also be written `test`) with the sole argument `"$3"`, and with an input redirection from the file `50`. Either use the numeric comparison operator `-lt`, or use an arithmetic instruction `(( … ))`. The single bracket construct is an ordinary built-in command, so special characters such as `<` retain their normal meaning. The double parenthesis construct is special syntax, and you can use `<` as a numeric comparison operator inside.
- `["$2" < 50 ]` is missing a space after the opening bracket.

Also the usual convention in shell scripts is to put a newline after `then` and `else`. Furthermore, instead of an `else` block that consists entirely of an `if` statement, you should use `elif`. And please indent consistently.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i s
declare -i m
declare -i h

if (( $3 < 50 )); then
  s=$3+10  m=$2  h=$1
elif (( $2 < 50 )); then
  s=$3-50  m=$2+1  h=$1
else
  s=$1-50  m=$2-50  h=$1+1
fi 

echo "$h:$m:$s"
```

P.S. I haven't reviewed your logic. You seem to be looking for `date +%T -d 'now + 10 seconds'`.

Comment: `[[ $3 < 50 ]]` compares $3 with 50 *lexicographically*, so if $3 is 6 for instance, the command returns false, since 6 comes after 5. use `(( ))` for arithmetic comparison.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, sorry for these dumb errors, it's one of my first scripts. Obviously, it's more different then coding then I thought. 
So fi is a command, the spaces are important, and [] is used for char/strings.
And yes it's what I want the script to do, not to get the present time + 10sc.
Thank you again.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed an error. I meant :
elif (( $2 < 59 )); then
  s=$3-50  m=$2+1  h=$1
else
  s=$3-50  m=0  h=$1+1
fi

Answer (score 0):

You forget to a `;` after the nested `fi` statement

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i s
declare -i m
declare -i h

if [ "$3" < 50 ]; then s=$3+10  m=$2  h=$1
        else if ["$2" < 50 ];
                then s=$3-50  m=$2+1  h=$1
                    else s=$1-50  m=$2-50  h=$1+1 ;fi 
fi 

echo "$h:$m:$s"
```